# Inconsistant JavaScript Return Values

Tags: javascript, null, undefined, return-value

Why does getElementById() return null if the ID doesn't exist and getElementsByClassName() returns undefined if the class doesn't exist? This seems like an inconsistency in the JavaScript language since both are DOM methods. For example:

```
console.log( document.getElementById('bogusID') ); // null
console.log( document.getElementsByClassName('bogusClass')[0] ); // undefined
```

I recently had to find out the hard way, having my program crash since I wrongly assumed both methods would return "undefined" on a fail.

Is there actually a reason for the different return values?

Comment: "_getElementsByClassName() returns undefined if the class doesn't exist_" No, it doesn't, in that case it returns an empty collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName('bogusClass')` returns an empty array and you are trying to access the zeroth element, which doesn't exist, so you get `undefined`.

Javascript, unlike other programming language *doesn't throw index out of range exception*, because indexes are implemented as properties and accessing a property which doesn't exists returns `undefined`.

In terms of checking and handling for `null` and `undefined`, both are `falsy` value in javascript and hence your code should be the same for both cases.

```
if(condition){
// Both undefined and null would not pass the condition.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
console.log( document.getElementById('bogusID') ); // null
```

Thats because there aren't bogusID items on your DOM so the return is null

```
console.log( document.getElementsByClassName('bogusClass')[0] ); // undefined
```

Thats because your getting the index 0 of an array that doesn't have an element at the 0 pointer. So the index 0 of the array isn't defined (undefined)

Comment: document.getElementById returns either an element it finds, or null if it does not find that element.  Here it is not finding the element, so returns null. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

document.getElementByClassName returns a HTML Collection, similar to an array of elements having that class.  If there are no such elements it returns an empty array, which is true in this case, the 0th element of an empty array is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how the program is defined internally for `getElementById() & getElementByClass` but according to mozilla documentation `getElementById()` basically returns a reference(object) to the element.

**ID**
eg: `element = document.getElementById()`
**Return Value**

**element** -
is a reference to an **[Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)** object, or null if an element with the specified ID is not in the document. In dom there should be only 1 ID with a same name so there is no reuse in ID name.

**Class**

eg:    var elements = element.getElementsByClassName(names);

getElementsByClassName() method returns a live **[HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)** containing all child **elements** which have all of the given class names. When called on the document object, the complete document is searched, including the root node.
In dom there should be only 1 ID with a same name so there is no reuse in ID name and also **[HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)** uses array to collect all the elements that are refered using classname.

**Undefined** means a variable has been declared but has not yet been assigned a value. On the other hand, **null** is an assignment value. It can be assigned to a variable as a representation of no value.

Also, undefined and null are two distinct types: undefined is a type itself (undefined) while null is an object.